# How do best to handle flixel android application switching?

Tags: android, flixel

I have a pretty extensive adventure game running on Android using [flixel-gdx](http://flixel-gdx.com/), and I would like to save the current game state when android switches to another application.

I know you can override the `onFocus()` and `onFocusLost()` methods on the `FlxGame` object, but I can't see a way of accessing the current game state from those methods. The only way I can see is to create a static object that holds a reference to the game state values, and refactor my entire game to reference the static object when it needs to manipulate those values.

Can anyone think of an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

```
FlxG.getState();
```

returns you the current state that is running.